# Is it possible to re-spec my character?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm playing Dark Souls 1 and since I know that in Dark Souls 2 you can re-spec your character using a Soul Vessel, I was wondering whether there is a similar item in Dark Souls 1.

**Is it possible to reset the points I spent in my character's attributes and place them on different attributes?**

In case this shouldn't be possible, how much sense is there in changing my character's build? I'm currently playing Paladin like (Heavy armor, 1-hand/2-handy swords and some miracles). I'm currently at level 45 and I wish I had spent more points in sorcery in order to be able to cast some damage spells or enchant my weapon. This [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85945/is-it-possible-to-to-mess-up-a-character-build-in-dark-souls) doesn't quite answer the question I have. *Will I destroy my build when I try to make a knight/sorcerer hybrid at Level 45?*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to respec your character in Dark Souls 1. The respec via a Soul Vessel was a new feature added to Dark Souls 2.

Answer (score 5):

### Restarting is quick

If you want to try sorceries, instead of getting a bunch of levels and required stat points it could easily be quicker to level up a new character based on sorcery from the start.

I was pleasantly surprised with how easy and quick it was to restart with a different spec - the same places and bosses that required a huge time investment in my initial exploration were easy even with the default starting gear simply because this time I knew how to defeat them.

Comment: I will definitely create a second char and see how well I get through with a sorcerer build!

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to edit your game data, which means manipulating your save file. There are some editor tools but I dont know how "legit" they are or what all the options in those editors are.

And about your problem with the build. It depends on what you want to do. If you want a PvP character you kind of need to start with the right build. But if you just want to play PvE there is no real way to "ruin" the game, you can always level and farm those points.

You can defeat the game with any build. You just need to learn to dodge more :P

**Edit:** Here are some editing tools for manipulating Xbox games save data:

- http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/608635-dark-souls/63809715
- http://www.game-tuts.com/community/f37/tut-using-basics-modio-xbox-game-saves-109352/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm playing on Xbox, so editing game data is not an option ;) I'm more a PvE player, so I think it's ok for me.

Comment: A quick google research showed that you can also edit Xbox Save games :D

Comment: @GEnGEr So if a quick google research showed that you can do that, provide a link or a source to back up your claims.

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/608635-dark-souls/63809715 
------ 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bcyADhGv5k ------ 
http://www.game-tuts.com/community/f37/tut-using-basics-modio-xbox-game-saves-109352/

in the first few links if you google "xbox savegame to pc dark souls"

Comment: It's definitely not legit or FROM approved but fairness will depend on the user. I feel using this editor is fair as long as people use the editor to respec (meaning take away points from one attribute to give to another).  You earned those points, you should be able to use them whatever way you want. An unfair usage and abuse would be to use this editor to max out your character so can do better in PvP. It also means the game will match make you people who earned the points fairly, that will be much better than you & you'll be killed.